# mail from website to external error although lampp dovecot and saslauthd already started at boot. When I restart lampp mail is sent

Tags: apache2, lamp, postfix

My boot order is

- saslauth started
- dovecot started
- postfix started
- lampp started.

There is no problem with internal and external sending and receiving mail only php mail code from website shows mail error. But when I restart lampp, then webmail works sending mail to Google.I restart lampp from terminal.

```
cd  /opt
cd lampp
./lampp restart

starting Apache with SSL ( and PHP)...
Starting Mysql
Starting ProFTPD
```

but these were already started at boot

Can you give me a solution? In webmin panel saslauthd , dovecot, xinetd, postfix and enabled at boot. Since friends apache lampp is installed in opt directory it is also set to start to auto boot with following commands

```
apache friends lampp is installed in  opt directory and is enabled auto start at boot with following  commands

ln -s /opt/lampp/lampp S99lampp
ln -s /opt/lampp/lampp K01lampp
```

However, in Webmin panel boot httpd service is showing no for auto start. Starting this enables another apache daemon.

Where is opt directory lampp installation showing auto start in boot pane? Also where is mysql and proftpd service in Webmin control panel?

---

Steff Thanks for understanding the peculiar problem: I deleted httpd at boot from webmin but could not run apt-get in centos or yum uninstall apache2. No error in log.
output at terminal pas auxwe command before opt lampp restart and after opt lampp restart : mail from website works after opt lampp restart but shows error before restart. But before lampp restart mail is sent and received from gmail and server.

Here's the output of `ps`: https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/161097

Answer (score 1):

> However in Webmin panel boot httpd service is showing no for auto start. Starting this enables another apache daemon.

Regarding the above, there may be two Apache2 installations in system conflicting each other. This could result one Apache2 instance to run at boot and one more the one Webmin sees.

To check which Apache2 Webmin sees, stop the the one running at boot with:

`./lampp stop`  (locatated at /opt/lampp)

Then go to Webmin and run the httpd daemon.

When the httpd daemon starts, issue the following in terminal:

`ps auxwe`

This will print all running processes with their paths. If the running Apache2 instance path is other than the one installed with lampp (the one located at /opt/lampp) then there is a strong possibility that there may be conflict in other services too like MySQL, etc.

Also a good place to check is /var/log/* (check for apache2/* logs, mysql.log and mail.* logs)

The procedure above may be used to find other potential conflicitng services like MySQL, Postfix, etc.

**Possible Solutions:**

- Uninstall one stack, that is either the LAMPP or the rest probable installed by the package manager (apt)
- Check the all startup scripts and stop the conflicting services
- Check the PHP source and see which service calls or tune it by giving a full path to the executable.